# How to call a method when user logs in using asp:login?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, authentication

I'm using the `asp:Login` to authenticate users on a website.  Is there a way I can call a method on login (C#)?  I want to get some user details from the database and save them in session for use later on.

I know I would be able to do this by redirecting to a 'blank' page with the correct code in the `Page_Load` event, and then redirect to the landing page when details have been retrieved.  I dont think this is good practice though?
I'm wondering if I could add this to the Login 'onclick' event?

Is that possible with `asp:login`?

Comment: All that is on the page is literally <asp:Login ID="LoginForm" runat="server" /> and onclick doesnt work with it

Comment: MY appologies, there is a OnLoggingIn ! I guess that should work.  Im too tired today :/

Answer (score 3):

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" OnLoggingIn="Authenticate">
</asp:Login>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void Authenticate(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{
    //Your authentication code...
}
```

**Some additional info:**

Transmitting passwords over HTTP is a potential security threat. HTTP transmissions can be viewed or compromised by malicious users. To improve security when using login controls, you should use HTTPS protocol with secure sockets layer (SSL) encryption to ensure that the user's password cannot be read during postback. For more information, see [Securing Login Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178346.aspx)